# How to join by closest timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a table of class start times and a table of students with their desired start times. I want to join the two tables by matching the closest Class.StartTime with Student.DesiredStartTime (see example below). How would you do that? 
I see the question frequently asked and answered, but only for other databases (not BigQuery). Since BigQuery has some unique attributes, I'm wondering if BigQuery has any special features to help this along?  Thanks!

```
Class
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               StartTime           |    Class   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| 07/01/19 08:00                    | English    |
| 07/01/19 09:00                    | Chemistry  |
| 07/01/19 10:30                    | Math       |
+-----------------------------------+------------+

Student
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|               DesiredStartTime    |    Student |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| 07/01/19 08:45                    | Jimmy      |
| 07/01/19 09:15                    | Bobby      |
| 07/01/19 10:00                    | Buddy      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+

[Query Results]
+-----------------------------------+------------+------------+
|               StartTime           |    Class   |  Student   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 07/01/19 09:00                    | Chemistry  | Jimmy      |
| 07/01/19 09:00                    | Chemistry  | Bobby      |
| 07/01/19 10:30                    | Math       | Buddy      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike a lot of other databases, this is a good time for a cross join in BQ.  The following query finds the absolute difference (in minutes) between a student's desired start time and ALL class start times, ranks them, and then picks the one that is closest.

```
with joined as (
  select 
    Student, 
    Class,
    StartTime,
    DesiredStartTime, 
    ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(StartTime,DesiredStartTime, MINUTE)) as abs_difference_mins
  from <dataset>.Class
  cross join <dataset>.Student
),
ranked as (
  select
    StartTime,
    Class,
    Student,
    row_number() over(partition by Student order by abs_difference_mins asc) as ranked_by_mins_diff
  from joined
)
select * except(ranked_by_mins_diff)
from ranked
where ranked_by_mins_diff = 1
```

Comment: Prefer the answer from Mikhail Berlyant without cross join as more performant and more scalable

Comment: Fair enough, obviously depends on your data. BigQuery can handle quite a bit (including cross joins) in a pretty performant way, so not sure this should be your biggest concern.  However, I find my code much more readable and easier to understand. If you are writing code that will be shared or inherited by other co-workers, my solution is quite easy to understand (event without comments) and uses basic SQL principles.  As computing power increases, I find myself worrying less about efficiency and more about trying to come up with simple solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and a little non-orthodox as first (really good) answer that is using CROSS JOIN (which is most likely OK for student-class use case, but can be a killer for more generic cases with really big data involved). So below is using UNION ALL instead thus dealing with `N+M` vs `NxM` intermediate rows

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) StartTime, IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) Class, Student 
  FROM (
    SELECT StartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(StartTime) ts, Class, '' Student FROM `project.dataset.class` 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DesiredStartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(DesiredStartTime), NULL, Student FROM `project.dataset.student` 
  )
  WINDOW 
    prev_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
    next_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE Student != ''
```

You can test, play with above, using dummy data like in your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.class` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-07-01 08:00:00' StartTime, 'English' Class UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-01 09:00:00', 'Chemistry' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-01 10:30:00', 'Math' 
), `project.dataset.student` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-07-01 08:45:00' DesiredStartTime, 'Jimmy' Student UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-01 09:15:00', 'Bobby' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-01 10:00:00', 'Buddy' 
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) StartTime, IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) Class, Student 
  FROM (
    SELECT StartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(StartTime) ts, Class, '' Student FROM `project.dataset.class` 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DesiredStartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(DesiredStartTime), NULL, Student FROM `project.dataset.student` 
  )
  WINDOW 
    prev_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
    next_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE Student != ''
```

with below result

```
Row StartTime                   Class       Student  
1   2019-07-01 09:00:00 UTC     Chemistry   Jimmy    
2   2019-07-01 09:00:00 UTC     Chemistry   Bobby    
3   2019-07-01 10:30:00 UTC     Math        Buddy
```

If `StartTime` and `DesiredStartTime` are STRINGs as it looks like from your question's example, you obviously need first to parse them out to TIMESTAMP as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.class` AS (
  SELECT '07/01/19 08:00' StartTime, 'English' Class UNION ALL
  SELECT '07/01/19 09:00', 'Chemistry' UNION ALL
  SELECT '07/01/19 10:30', 'Math' 
), `project.dataset.student` AS (
  SELECT '07/01/19 08:45' DesiredStartTime, 'Jimmy' Student UNION ALL
  SELECT '07/01/19 09:15', 'Bobby' UNION ALL
  SELECT '07/01/19 10:00', 'Buddy' 
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(StartTime IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) StartTime, IF(
    ts - LAST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win) < FIRST_VALUE(ts IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, 
    LAST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), FIRST_VALUE(Class IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win)
    ) Class, Student 
  FROM (
    SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', StartTime) StartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', StartTime)) ts, Class, '' Student FROM `project.dataset.class` 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', DesiredStartTime), UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', DesiredStartTime)), NULL, Student FROM `project.dataset.student` 
  )
  WINDOW 
    prev_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
    next_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE Student != ''
```

Comment: This solution will return `NULL` for any students' `DesiredStartTime` later than the largest `StartTime` in class. Try change Buddy's DesiredStartTime to 11:00. Any fix for that?

Comment: I will check this

Comment: Context of this post/question is such that if desiredstarttime is greater than any class's start time - such student is out of luck, and thus there is no any match for such student. If you still want to have such a student in the final output - you can left join current result with original list of users. Very simple adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I think the goal of this question is to find closest timestamp record of students table from class table. It did not specify restriction about time. I post my answer based on yours and fix two issues I found. BTW, this answer is great, thanks for inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you, slightly "BQ"-ish fashion. :-)

```
SELECT Student, item.StartTime, item.Class FROM (
    SELECT s.Student as Student, 
         ARRAY_AGG(
           STRUCT(
             c.StartTime as StartTime,
             c.Class AS Class, 
             ABS(UNIX_SECONDS(s.DesiredStartTime) - UNIX_SECONDS(c.StartTime)) AS Delta 
           ) 
           ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_SECONDS(s.DesiredStartTime) - UNIX_SECONDS(c.StartTime))
      )[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS item
    FROM student s
    LEFT JOIN class c ON 1 = 1
    GROUP BY 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified from Mikhail Berlyant's answer. I think there are two issues with that answer:

1. The `StartTime` of final result should be only from class table, so I add a filter inside each `LAST_VALUE` and `FIRST_VALUE` expressions.
2. The original solution will return `NULL` for all students' `DesiredStartTime` later than the largest `StartTime` in class. Note that I update Bubby to 11:00.

   The reason is that both last previous record `LAST_VALUE(...)` and first next record `FIRST_VALUE(...)` could be `NULL`. For those students records rank in the end, their `FIRST_VALUE(...)` is `NULL`. This will cause the the comparison to return `NULL`. BigQuery consider `NULL` as `False`. But for those cases it should be `True` because we need to return `LAST_VALUE(...)`.

   To fix this, I convert those possible `NULL`s to infinity value so they should always return the one with value.

```
WITH
  `project.dataset.class` AS (
      SELECT '07/01/19 08:00' StartTime, 'English' Class UNION ALL
      SELECT '07/01/19 09:00', 'Chemistry' UNION ALL
      SELECT '07/01/19 10:30', 'Math' ),
  `project.dataset.student` AS (
      SELECT '07/01/19 6:45' DesiredStartTime, 'Jimmy' Student UNION ALL
      SELECT '07/01/19 09:29', 'Bobby' UNION ALL
      SELECT '07/01/19 11:00', 'Buddy' )
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    IF
      (
        IFNULL(ts - LAST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', ts , NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), CAST('inf' AS float64)) < 
        IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, CAST('inf' AS float64)
      ),
      LAST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', StartTime, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win),
      FIRST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', StartTime, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) 
      ) StartTime,
    IF
      (
        IFNULL(ts - LAST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', ts , NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win), CAST('inf' AS float64)) < 
        IFNULL(FIRST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', ts, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) - ts, CAST('inf' AS float64)
      ),
      LAST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', Class, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(prev_win),
      FIRST_VALUE(IF(Student = '', Class, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(next_win) 
      ) Class,
    Student
  FROM (
    SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', StartTime) StartTime, UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', StartTime)) ts, Class, '' Student FROM `project.dataset.class` 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', DesiredStartTime), UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%D %R', DesiredStartTime)), NULL, Student FROM `project.dataset.student`
    )
  WINDOW
    prev_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
    next_win AS (ORDER BY StartTime ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
WHERE
  Student != ''
```